# When does ember destroy controller instances

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering when Ember does garbage collection for all the controller objects. I had route structure like :

```
AS.Router.map(function () {

            this.resource('employee', function () {
                this.route('basics');
                this.route('services');
                this.route('advanced');
            });

});
```

I have noticed that when I move from basics route to services route, the EmployeeBasicsController is not getting destroyed. I am not sure if it is by design, or I would have to do it manually(using the destroy action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design, Ember uses singleton instances by default.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion as to how to properly destroy the instances then? I am asking because we are trying to limit the memory usage by our app (for slower browsers like ie8).

Comment: I feel your pain, we are in a similar situation having to support IE8 as well.  It's hard to decide whether or not you gain more performance by having the controller already available or by disposing the controller for memory sake.  Generally IE8 has more of an issue with running a ton of javascript at once (without relinquishing control) than it does with memory issues.  Having the controller already available probably helps more than it hurts.  Now depending on data you are bringing down, I'd see more to gain by cleaning out your local data models than cleaning our controllers.

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha have you tried calling `destroy()` on the controller? That should cause it to get cleaned up in the next run loop.

Comment: @spinlock : I actually did, but when I revisited the route whose controller I had already destroyed, things got messed up - I just assumed that it was because the app expects to have an "active" controller. Ultimately I left my route based controllers as dummy as possible(i thought much of the slowness must have been due to large no of observes we needed) and then I ended up using "render" helper to create new instances of controllers(not the same controllers as route based one) and destroy them when they go out of context which I believe helped quite a bit(100% just feel basis)